# Shape of electron

Tags: electrons, standard-model, elementary-particles, point-particles

Today, in the BBC Science section, a headline reads that the Imperial College of London has determined that the shape of the electron is completely spherical.  In a physics book I'm reading now, the authors indicate that visualizing elementary particles as tiny balls is not correct.  They are essentially point sources with mass but no volume.  The electron is not an object, it is a probabilistic "object" like a cloud.  How do I make sense of this.

Comment: I can't find such web page on BBS Science. Could you add a link to it?